# How to applied teamViewApi in javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, remote-access, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm a beginner for javascript integrate with teamViewer API. I had do some researches but unable to find relevant source. is there any way to implement it? i would like to use teamViewer api to create an easy access webpage to remote my device without using teamviewer software.

Comment: You should provide more information, where are you stuck? do you have an access token, did you get success responses?

Comment: You cannot use the API to remote connect to a device through your browser, see the [documentation](https://integrate.teamviewer.com/en/develop/api/documentation/). You can use the [TeamViewer Management Console](https://login.teamviewer.com/) for this, but only if you have a license.